# How to exclude generated code from a code coverage report?

Tags: java, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, coveralls

I've got the following `jacoco-maven-plugin` configuration:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/Header*.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Which should exclude from a code coverage report all generated java files that begin with `Header`. Unfortunately, I still see these classes in my code coverage report which makes the `coveralls-maven-plugin` fail when I call the `coveralls:report`. The error I get when I call `coveralls:report` is:

`: No source found for HeaderMyClass.java ->`

Which makes me think that the JaCoCo coverage report still contains the data for this class which was automatically generated.

Answer (score 2):

Just add exclusions for `report` goal in jacoco-maven-plugin configuration

```
<execution>
  <id>coverage-report</id>
  <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>report</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*Dto.class</exclude>
      <exclude>com/foo/config/*</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the pattern to:

```
  <excludes>
    <exclude>**/Header*.*</exclude>
  </excludes>
```

did the trick